# Conflict between DT and Plotly to show NA in table

Tags: r, shiny, dt, r-plotly

There is a solution to show `NA` or `Inf` values in a table created with DT using `options(htmlwidgets.TOJSON_ARGS = list(na = 'string'))` as described [here](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/496#issuecomment-363867449).

The problem is that `htmlwidgets.TOJSON_ARGS` is also affecting plotly. Below is simple example of the problem.

```R
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(plotly)

options(htmlwidgets.TOJSON_ARGS = list(na = 'string'))
dat <- data.frame(x = c(1, NA, NA, 4, 5), y = 1:5)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    plotlyOutput("plot"),
    DTOutput('tbl')
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$plot <- renderPlotly({
      plot_ly(data = dat, x =~x, y =~y)
    })
    output$tbl = renderDataTable(dat)
  }
)
```

The table correctly shows `NA` values but the plot does not work and shows `Error: formal argument "na" matched by multiple actual arguments`

Could be possible to set `htmlwidgets.TOJSON_ARGS` to affect only the table but not the plot? Or what are the correct parameters to use in order to avoid that error with plotly?

The code above is s very basic example, the solution should work with multiple tables and plots dynamically created as user interact with data. So, removing `options(htmlwidgets.TOJSON_ARGS = list(na = 'string'))` and convert data to string is not an option since it will break the sorting functionality of the table. Neither using a custom JS code in `columnDefs` parameter of table to display `NA`, because it will be inefficient for large datasets.

Any recommendation or comment would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dev version of DT now has a new option `DT.TOJSON_ARGS` which should fix your problem. See [rstudio/DT#536](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/pull/536).

Comment: Thank you, I [reported it](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/pull/513#issuecomment-383704420) and they fixed it really fast.